# Inside Playa {if no_coparents}, display channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, playa

I have a channel entries tag which displays Videos and then a playa pair tag (coparents) which displays related videos based on a specific field.

Now, I would like to display other videos (let's say the last two entries of the "video" channel) in case no related videos are found. I tried with `{if no_coparents}...{/if}` but no luck so far since I don't manage to display video channel entries inside those tags.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="video" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" status="open" transcribe="disable"}
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  {video_file}
  {video_description}

  <div class="block-related three columns">
    <h2 class="first-title">Related Videos</h2>
    {exp:playa:coparents channel="video" field="video_related_field" dynamic="no" limit="2"}
      <div>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            {if video_flickr_thumbnail}
            <img src="{video_flickr_thumbnail}" alt="{title}">
            {if:elseif video_thumbnail}
            <img src="{video_thumbnail}" alt="{title}">
            {/if}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    {/exp:playa:coparents}

{!-- Now here I would like to get something in case there isn't any related video.
It would be great if I could just call {exp:channel:entries channel="video"}
to retrieve the last two videos. I tried with {if no_coparents} ... {/if}
but no luck so far. --}

  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Macxim - I just tested {if no_coparents} with great success here:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="10"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{exp:playa:coparents}
{if no_coparents}
no coparents
{/if}
parent entry id: {parent:entry_id}<br />
{/exp:playa:coparents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Can I ask you to try this code in a template and see what results you get?  Just copy/paste the above into a template.  You may need a few recent tests with coparents and without.  I made this as minimal as possible to test it.

Please let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hello Lisa, thank your for your answer. Unfortunately, still no luck with that. **no coparents** was displayed even if the entry **did** have coparents.

Comment: You tried with the exact code, and nothing else, Macxim?   It may be time for me to login and have a look.  Is that possible? If so, please email super admin details to support@pixelandtonic.com, and reference this thread.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [embed](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html) your alternative Channel Entries loop in this case.

```
{exp:playa:coparents channel="video" field="video_related_field" dynamic="no" limit="2"}
    <!-- snip -->
    {if no_coparents}
        {embed="videos/_related"}
    {/if}
{/exp:playa:coparents}
```

Comment: I was afraid someone would answer this. Isn't there any other option? Would a snippet do the thing?

Comment: Just to be sure, `{if no_coparents}...{/if}` has to be inside the {exp:playa:coparents} loop? Just asking because it is not currently working. The content of {if no_coparents} appears even if there _is_ coparents. Weird.

Comment: Yes, the conditional has to be inside the `playa:coparents` tag. A snippet will not work, as it's just replaced before parsing. The issue is that you would be nesting a `channel:entries` tag inside another `channel:entries` tag, causing massive variable collision. An embed is the way to go.

Comment: Do you have any clue about why the `{if no_coparents}...{/if}` is not working? I even checked with `{exp:playa:total_coparents}`, but the `{if no_parents}` is completely ignored, the content shows up, no matter what.

Comment: Try with something simple, like `{if no_coparents}There were no co-parents.{/if}`.

Comment: In entries where there is, for example 2 coparents, the sentence were displayed twice. However, when there are indeed **no** coparents, nothing shows up.

Comment: Hi, Macxim - can you let me know what version of EE and Playa you're on before we continue troubleshooting?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Lisa. Here you go: EE => 2.5.3 / Playa => 4.3.3